# SED switching columns in one file delimited by ,

Tags: sed, awk, grep, cut

I have a file with 65k lines looking like this:

```
Mumford & Sons,Wilder Mind (Deluxe),Believe - Live,02 Oct 2016 10:25            
Mumford & Sons,Wilder Mind (Deluxe),Tompkins Square Park,02 Oct 2016 10:19          
Mumford & Sons,Wilder Mind (Deluxe),Believe,02 Oct 2016 10:16               
Bon Iver,22 A Million,00000 Million,02 Oct 2016 10:06           
Bon Iver,22 A Million,____45_____,02 Oct 2016 10:03         
Bon Iver,22 A Million,8 (circle),02 Oct 2016 09:58
```

I have been trying a lot, but I cant get it done. I need it to look like this:

```
Mumford & Sons,Believe - Live,Wilder Mind (Deluxe),02 Oct 2016 10:25
```

so that second column is switched with the third one. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: so its actually not a column, its a one-liner one big text string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

`awk -F, '{A=$3; $3=$2; $2=A; print}' OFS=, yourfile`

Basically `-F` says that you separate columns by `,`, the body switches 2nd with 3rd column, and then you `print` the modified line.

Comment: Just found one snippet: awk -F, '{print $1,$3,$2,$4}' OFS=, oldfile.txt > newfile.txt works.! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: yours working too, but then the "," is missing.

Comment: @jsterr yeah, just added. Forgot about `OFS`. I thought about the solution that you provided, but I wasn't sure about the amount of columns, and your solution only prints first four(if for some reason your file is allowed to have variable number of columns).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)/\1,\3,\2,\4/' file

Mumford & Sons,Believe - Live,Wilder Mind (Deluxe),02 Oct 2016 10:25            
Mumford & Sons,Tompkins Square Park,Wilder Mind (Deluxe),02 Oct 2016 10:19          
Mumford & Sons,Believe,Wilder Mind (Deluxe),02 Oct 2016 10:16               
Bon Iver,00000 Million,22 A Million,02 Oct 2016 10:06           
Bon Iver,____45_____,22 A Million,02 Oct 2016 10:03         
Bon Iver,8 (circle),22 A Million,02 Oct 2016 09:58
```